# React runs via Axios Mysql Query twice

Tags: mysql, reactjs, double, rows

I'm running into a double execution of my axios request in a functional react-app, which by random inserts 1 or 2 rows instead of always just 1 row into the database. Tried to wrap it in a useEffect-Hook...did not help. By logging the execution function it seems only to run once. But on the php-side it's kind of executed twice. The strange thing is, that I've implemented the same thing in two other parts of the app (just different items) and there the same code just works fine...any help very appreciated! Thx in advance!

Js-Code in React:

```
function ReservationObjectsDialogAdd() {
  const appState = useContext(StateContext)
  const appDispatch = useContext(DispatchContext)

  const [name, setName] = useState()

  const handleKeyPressAddDialog = e => {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      setReservationObject()
    }
  }

  // add new category
  async function setReservationObject() {
    try {
      // set new Category
      const response = await Axios.post("/Main.php?cmd=setReservationObject", { name })
      console.log(response.data)

      appDispatch({ type: "getReservationObjects" })
      appDispatch({ type: "setOpenAddDialog", data: false })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
      console.log(lang.reservationObjectAddProblem)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Dialog open={appState.openAddDialog} onClose={e => appDispatch({ type: "setOpenAddDialog", data: false })} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
      <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">{lang.addTimeName}</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <TextField onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} autoFocus margin="dense" id="name" label={lang.timeName} type="text" fullWidth required={true} onKeyPress={handleKeyPressAddDialog} />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={e => appDispatch({ type: "setOpenAddDialog", data: false })} color="primary">
          {lang.cancel}
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={setReservationObject} color="primary">
          {lang.add}
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  )
}

export default ReservationObjectsDialogAdd
```

PHP-Side:

```
case "setReservationObject":

    $conn = new DBConnection($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $db);
    $post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $maxOrder = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(orderNumber) as maxorder FROM reservationObjects", [])->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $maxOrder = $maxOrder['maxorder'] + 1;
    $activeCategory = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM reservationCategories WHERE active=?", [1])->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO reservationObjects (category,name,orderNumber,visible) values(?,?,?,?)", [$activeCategory['id'], $post['name'], $maxOrder, 1]);

    break;
```

Here the rendering-code:

```
function ReservationObjects() {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const appState = useContext(StateContext)
  const appDispatch = useContext(DispatchContext)

  const [reservationObjects, setReservationObjects] = useState([])

  const [images, setImages] = useState()

  //sort categories
  function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {
    let newReservationObjects = reservationObjects.map((el, i) => {
      return el
    })

    newReservationObjects = arrayMove(newReservationObjects, oldIndex, newIndex)

    setReservationObjects(newReservationObjects)

    async function sortObjects(newReservationObjects) {
      try {
        // sort Data in DB
        const response = await Axios.post("/Main.php?cmd=sortObjects", { reservationObjects: newReservationObjects })

        appDispatch({ type: "getReservationObjects" })
        appDispatch({ type: "getReservationItems" })
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        console.log(lang.categorySortProblem)
      }
    }
    sortObjects(newReservationObjects)
  }

  // sort events- part 1
  function handleDragEndSortObjects(event) {
    const { active, over } = event

    if (active.id !== over.id) {
      const tempReservationObjects = reservationObjects.map((el, i) => {
        return el
      })
      let oldIndex = null
      let newIndex = null
      tempReservationObjects.map((el, i) => {
        if (active.id == el.id) {
          oldIndex = i
        }
        if (over.id == el.id) {
          newIndex = i
        }
      })
      onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex })
    }
  }

  function handleDragEndAssignObjects(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }

  // in Sort-Mode check if the clicked target is a interface-entity
  function shouldCancelStart(e) {
    console.log("enter should cancel")
    if (e.target.hasAttribute("isadmin")) {
      if (e.target.attributes.isadmin.value) {
        console.log("enter should cancel return false")
        return false
      }
    }
    if (e.target.hasAttribute("interface")) {
      if (e.target.attributes.interface.value) {
        console.log("enter should cancel return true")
        return true
      }
    }
  }

  // initial loading of reservation objects
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getReservationObjects() {
      try {
        const response = await Axios.post("/Main.php?cmd=getReservationObjects", { isadmin: appState.isAdmin, category: appState.activeCategoryNumber }).then(response => {
          setReservationObjects(response.data)
          appDispatch({ type: "getReservationTimes" })
        })
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(lang.reservationCategoriesProblem)
      }
    }
    getReservationObjects()
  }, [appState.getReservationObjectsTrigger])

  //initial loading of images
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadImages() {
      try {
        const response = await Axios.post("/Main.php?cmd=getImages")
        //console.log(response.data)
        setImages(response.data)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
      }
    }
    loadImages()
  }, [])

  // handle mouse leave -> background Image
  function handleObjectMouseLeave(e) {
    appDispatch({ type: "setBackgroundImage", data: "" })
  }

  //handle mouse enter -> background Image
  function handleObjectMouseEnter(e) {
    if (e.target.hasAttribute("image")) {
      let image = e.target.attributes.image.value
      appDispatch({ type: "setBackgroundImage", data: image })
    }
  }

  const sensors = useSensors(
    useSensor(PointerSensor),
    useSensor(KeyboardSensor, {
      coordinateGetter: sortableKeyboardCoordinates
    })
  )

  function Draggable(props) {
    const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, isDragging, over } = useDraggable({
      id: props.id,
      category: props.category
    })
    const style = transform
      ? {
          transform: `translate3d(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px, 0)`
        }
      : undefined

    return (
      <div ref={setNodeRef} className="reservationArea__reservationObjectDraggable" style={style} {...listeners} {...attributes}>
        <ReservationObject category={props.category} key={props.id} id={props.id} name={props.name} hover={appState.hoverObjectId == props.id ? "hovering" : ""} visible={props.visible} isadmin={appState.isAdmin.toString()} id={props.id} isactive={props.active} hovered={appState.reservationItems} image={props.image} onMouseEnter={handleObjectMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleObjectMouseLeave} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  function sortableVsDroppable() {
    if (appState.objectsSortable) {
      return (
        <DndContext sensors={sensors} collisionDetection={closestCenter} onDragEnd={handleDragEndSortObjects}>
          <SortableContext
            items={reservationObjects.map(item => {
              return item.id
            })}
            strategy={horizontalListSortingStrategy}
            className="reservationArea__reservationObjects"
          >
            <div className="reservationArea__reservationObjects">
              {reservationObjects.map((item, i) => (
                <ReservationObject key={item.id} id={item.id} name={item.name} hover={appState.hoverObjectId == item.id ? "hovering" : ""} visible={item.visible} isadmin={appState.isAdmin.toString()} id={item.id} isactive={item.active} hovered={appState.reservationItems} image={item.image} onMouseEnter={handleObjectMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleObjectMouseLeave} />
              ))}
            </div>
            {appState.isAdmin ? (
              <Link to="/" onClick={e => appDispatch({ type: "setOpenAddDialog", data: true })} className="reservationArea__addObject">
                <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
              </Link>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </SortableContext>
        </DndContext>
      )
    } else {
      console.log("assignable")
      return (
        <>
          <div className="reservationArea__reservationObjects">
            {reservationObjects.map((item, i) => (
              <Draggable key={item.id} category={item.category} id={item.id} index={item.id} name={item.name} hover={appState.hoverObjectId == item.id ? "hovering" : ""} visible={item.visible} isadmin={appState.isAdmin.toString()} id={item.id} isactive={item.active} hovered={appState.reservationItems} image={item.image} onMouseEnter={handleObjectMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleObjectMouseLeave} />
            ))}
          </div>
          {appState.isAdmin ? (
            <Link to="/" onClick={e => appDispatch({ type: "setOpenAddDialog", data: true })} className="reservationArea__addObject">
              <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
            </Link>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </>
      )
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="reservationArea__reservationObjectsContainer">
      <ReservationObjectsImage />

      {sortableVsDroppable()}
      <ReservationObjectsDialogAdd />
      <ReservationObjectsDialogEdit />
      <ReservationObjectsDialogDelete />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ReservationObjects
```

Comment: Here you can see what happens in the app: https://recordit.co/M18FnajjUk

Comment: Can't tell from that gif if you are invoking `setReservationObject` twice or only once, or how many requests are made. Have you verified you are making only a single API request? This seems to be an issue with wherever you are rending the UI. Can you update your question to include the render code?

Comment: Just added the rendering code. If i log the execution of ```setReservationObject()```, it only logs it once.

Comment: As u can see here, the ```setReservationObject()``` is executed only once. And if you watch the addition of the objects, once it adds two items, once it adds only one (which would be correct). https://recordit.co/mzJA3ygaEr

Comment: So if I read correctly, you are mapping into props for `SortableContext`? Try reducing your code down to a much simpler component, sans the sorting/dragging/moving/etc of array elements to see where it's breaking. The `arrayMove` seems suspect to me.

Comment: Yes I'm mapping into props for ```SortableContext```. The aim is to have as well the possibility to sort the objects, as well as assigning them to parent-categories (which is toggled by the ```appState.objectsSortable```. The ```arrayMove``` comes only into play if I in fact sort the objects, which I'm not doing. All I do is adding new objects and there is the confusing thing....Btw. wouldn't know how to reduce this even more *shame ;-)

Comment: Cut out all the render code and render something stupid simple like `reservationObjects.map(el => <div>{/* whatever you need from el */}</div>)`. If you see no duplicates then move on to the next slightly more complex rendering logic, repeat until it breaks, then drill into *that* area. The issue could be in this code, or it might be in `SortableContext`. IMO this `ReservationObjectsDialogAdd` has a lot going on in it.

Comment: Just did as you said (rendering only simple ```reservationObjects``` with ```map```. Same thing....seems the bug already exists at the rendering time...Thx a lot @Drew Reese , will have another deep look into it!

Comment: Yeah, I guess you need to work back the other way for all the logic that touches `reservationObjects` locally in that component, back to where it's fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. It was in the php-part. I replaced the fetching of the activeCategory directly in mysql with a parameter that I sent with Axios. Somehow the activeCategory-fetching led to to this strange behaviour, that it randmly executed the insert-statement once or twice.